# PyTorch naive single label classification with embedding layer fails at random

Tags: python, machine-learning, embedding, pytorch, random-seed

I am new to PyTorch and I am trying out the Embedding Layer.

I wrote a naive classification task, where all the inputs are the equal and all the labels are set to 1.0. I hence expect the model to learn quickly to predict 1.0.

The input is always 0, which is fed into a nn.Embedding(1,32) layer, followed by nn.Linear(32,1) and nn.Relu().

However, an unexpected and undesired behavior occurs: training outcome is different for different times I run the code.
For example,

- setting the random seed to 10, model converges: loss decreases and model always predicts 1.0
- setting the random seed to 1111, model doesn't converge: loss doesn't decrease and model always predicts 0.5. In those cases the parameters are not updated

Here is the minimal, replicable code:

```
from torch.nn import BCEWithLogitsLoss
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import torch


class MyModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.vgg_fc = nn.Linear(32, 1)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.embeddings = nn.Embedding(1, 32)

    def forward(self, data):
        emb = self.embeddings(data['index'])
        return self.relu(self.vgg_fc(emb))


class MyDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __len__(self):
        return 1000
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return {'label': 1.0, 'index': 0}


def train():
    model = MyModel()
    db = MyDataset()
    dataloader = DataLoader(db, batch_size=256, shuffle=True, num_workers=16)

    loss_function = BCEWithLogitsLoss()
    optimizer_rel = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)

    for epoch in range(50):
        for i_batch, sample_batched in enumerate(dataloader):

            model.zero_grad()
            out = model({'index': Variable(sample_batched['index'])})

            labels = Variable(sample_batched['label'].type(torch.FloatTensor).view(sample_batched['label'].shape[0], 1))

            loss = loss_function(out, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer_rel.step()
            print 'Epoch:', epoch, 'batch', i_batch, 'Tr_Loss:', loss.data[0]
    return model


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # please, try seed 10 (converge) and seed 1111 (fails)
    torch.manual_seed(10)
    train()
```

Without specifying the random seed, different runs have different outcome.

Why is, in those cases, the model unable to learn such a easy task?
Is there any mistake in the way I use nn.Embedding layer?

Thank you

Comment: What is the data you are using? Is it text? I guess no because you have `self.embeddings = nn.Embedding(1, 32)` which means you have just one feature. Seed makes a difference because the operations are non-deterministic in CuDNN.

Comment: @WasiAhmad, thank you for your comment! Well, for this trivial example, data is just a list of 1000 samples, each one is {'index':0 , 'label':1.0}. So, index=0 will always select the first (and only one) embedding vector in self.embeddings. This example is quite naive, but indeed I expect the model to always learn to predict 1.0, but that only happens for some seed... if I can't even learn this simple task, I am not sure I can extend to more complex cases.

Comment: well, I am assuming you are considering this as a regression task then. However, you are computing loss as `BCEWithLogitsLoss ` which means you are treating the task as binary classification but you are providing examples of only one class. Remember, neural network doesn't do any magic, it learns from the data you provide. Long story short, I would you are not doing the correct thing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was the final relu layer, before the sigmoid.
As stated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163695/non-linearity-before-final-softmax-layer-in-a-convolutional-neural-network), that layer will:

> throw away information without adding any additional benefit

Removing the layer, the network learned as expected with any seed.